MacOS Notarization fails due to COPYRIGHT and LICENSE files in bundled JRE created by jpackage not being signed
I now expect Apple to have moved the goalposts every time we come to do a release build and will have to fiddle with the packaging scripts.
Environment:

Java 21.0.4+8-LTS-274
MacOS Sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91)

Script snippets
jpackage \
--dest /Users/alanwhite/git/drumscore/DrumScore/bundles \
--app-version "${APP_VERSION}" \
--copyright 'Copyright (c) 2024 Alan R. White' \
--name 'DrumScoreEditor' \
--vendor 'drumscore.scot' \
--input /Users/alanwhite/git/drumscore/DrumScore/autobuild/target/build \
--main-jar "DrumScoreEditor-${APP_VERSION}.jar" \
--main-class org.whiteware.DrumScoreEditor \
--java-options '--add-opens java.desktop/com.apple.eawt.event=ALL-UNNAMED' \
--file-associations /Users/alanwhite/git/drumscore/DrumScore/autobuild/filetypes.txt \
--resource-dir /Users/alanwhite/git/drumscore/DrumScore/package/macosx \
--mac-package-name 'Drum Score Editor' \
--mac-package-signing-prefix 'org.whiteware.DrumScoreEditor' \
--mac-sign \
--mac-signing-key-user-name 'Alan White (XXXXXXXX)' \
--add-modules java.base,java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.prefs,java.xml,java.logging

We then xcrun notarytool submit and this fails, logs show:
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "DrumScoreEditor_macOS_arm64_3.2.1.dmg/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087735",
      "architecture": "arm64"
    }

Checking this as follows:
codesign -vvv --strict runtime/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
runtime/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.datatransfer/COPYRIGHT
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.datatransfer/LICENSE
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.desktop/COPYRIGHT
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.desktop/LICENSE
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.logging/COPYRIGHT
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.logging/LICENSE
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.prefs/COPYRIGHT
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.prefs/LICENSE
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.xml/COPYRIGHT
file modified: /Volumes/DrumScoreEditor/DrumScoreEditor.app/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.xml/LICENSE

And then individually checking ...
codesign -vvv --strict runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.datatransfer/COPYRIGHT
runtime/Contents/Home/legal/java.datatransfer/COPYRIGHT: code object is not signed at all

All of this wasn't an issue last week, jdk hasn't changed, what's the best way to go about solving this as cracking open the DMG produced by jpackage and signing these files seems wrong, should jpackage do this, should they have signatures from the idk provider, am I barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks folks.

Bizarrely, currently if I provide jpackage with a jre from jlink instead of letting jpackage build it itself everything gets signed properly. What makes it bizarre is the jlink command I'm using I pulled from a --verbose run of jpackage.

The bundle structure appears incorrect.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Thanks. That’s a jpackage issue if so as it’s been building them that way since its release many moons ago. I will debug what behaviours change in jpackage when it runs jlink vs supplying a runtime image provided by jlink when time permits and raise any needed bugs. That’s a working workaround for now.
